# Calling class method inside string format

Tags: python, string, format

Consider this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now() 
now.strftime("%p") # returns 'PM'
'{0.day}'.format(now) # returns 22

'{0.strftime("%p")}'.format(now)
# gives
# AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'strftime("%p")'
```

This seems to imply that I can't call a class method inside the format (I guess that's what `strftime` is).

What's a workaround for this (assuming I need to call the method inside the string, and keep using a format) ?

Comment: Do you actually need ``str.format``? An f-string has no problem with that.

Comment: Unfortunately I also have other placeholders in the same string, for example think of `{0.day}`, `{0.year}`, and there are `{1}`, `{2}`, etc too. I know about f-strings, but in this specific case I'd like to still work with `str.format`

Comment: `0.day` isn't an attribute lookup; it's special syntax provided by the `format` function.

Comment: how's this relevant @chepner ?

Comment: In this special case, `datetime` objects provide their own extension to the format mini language: `'{0:%p}'.format(now)`. In general, anything in the format following `:` is passed as a string to the `__format__` method of the argument being formatted.

Comment: It's relevant because you seem to think that `0.day` translates directly to `now.day`; it doesn't. It's `0`, a `.`, and a string, not an arbitrary Python expression.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your comment about `:`, but I don't get the one about `.`. Maybe a link to the documentation would help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> '{0:%p}'.format(now)
'PM'
```

This will also work with `f`-strings.

```
>>> f"{now:%p}"
'PM'
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed, thanks ! will accept as soon as I can

Answer (score 2):

You can use the f-string:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now() 
now.strftime("%p") # returns 'PM'
'{0.day}'.format(now) # returns 22

print(f'{now.strftime("%p")}')
```

---

Else:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now() 
now.strftime("%p") # returns 'PM'
'{0.day}'.format(now) # returns 22
print('{0:%p}'.format(now))
```

**Documentation**

- [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

You could use f-strings like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now() 
now.strftime("%p")
print(f'{now.day}')

print(f'{now.strftime("%p")}')
```